# Сохранение видео на Android

Tags: android, unity3d, архитектура, клиент-сервер

Unity.
Каким образом лучше всего скачивать видео с ftp сервера и сохранять их в папку использую Unity?

Answer (score 0):

1. А вам точно нужен FTP? Если у вас доступ не по паролю, то можно обойтись обычным http и `UnityWebRequest`.
2. Если, всё же, нужен ftp, то средствами Юнити это нормально не сделать. Можно использовать .NET класс [`FtpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), но сомневаюсь, что на мобильных платформах оно заработает.